# Overflow long text

Tags: css, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a code like in snippet below

```
      <p:dataTable 
                        rendered="#{Controller.lazyDataModel.rowCount > 0 }"
                        value="#{AuditController.lazyDataModel}"
                        var="event" paginator="true" 
                        paginatorTemplate=" {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100" lazy="true"
                        dynamic="false"
                        rows="25" 
                        loadingMessage="#{msgs.lsd_loading}">
                        <p:column width="300" overflow-x="visible">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText
                                    value="#{msgs.lsd_audit_details}" style="width:500; overflow-x:visible"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{event.eventDetails}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
```

but it renders like on image, the long rows are cutted by cells borders.

[image]

How should I add correct overflow tag to table row which shows all data?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-overflow. It's an attribute you can use on your column content definition, not a tag.

Comment: your want to overflow in each cell or row?

Comment: yes, it's will be render for other cells automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. All troubles was in result string it was single, long text without white-spaces.